# Create dataframe with new columns derived from unique values in a single column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe formatted like this:

| id | fieldname | fieldvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PC | Dell |
| 1 | Phone | Pixel 6 |
| 2 | PC | Lenovo |
| 3 | Phone | Samsung |

I would like to transform it to :

| id | PC | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dell | Pixel6 |
| 2 | Lenovo |  |
| 3 |  | Samsung |

In other words, create one column per distinct value in column *fieldname*, fill it with corresponding value from *fieldvalue*.

How would I do that in pyspark ?

Comment: Yoy can also try with fillna if you dont want null value in your column.
df.groupby("id").pivot("fieldname").agg(F.first("fieldvalue")).fillna("").show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a row to column problem should use [pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot).

```
df = df.groupBy('id').pivot('fieldname').agg(F.first('fieldvalue'))
```